# Dyamic line animation

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I'm having a bit of trouble making an animated line appear to be drawn from one element to another.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Proof of concept]

When the user clicks on the button, a line will appear to be "drawn" out, starting from the div and then ending on the button that has just been pressed.

I attempted to achieve this using Svg's, positioned absolutely within the elements, then using the `stroke-dashoffset` hack to make them look like they were being drawn in, but I couldn't dynamically alter the middle SVG line using jQuery.

So, what do you all think? Is using SVG's for the lines a bad idea? Or am I just not on the right path with this?

The lines have to connect to multiple different buttons from the same starting point (the div), and the whole thing has to work responsively as well... just to make it a little more difficult.

Any suggestions?

Comment: jQuery is not the right choice to edit SVGs. See [this](http://noeticforce.com/Javascript-libraries-for-svg-animation) list for more suitable libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question intrigued me. In my regular day job, I tend to approach problems in a three step process:

1) Make it work
2) Clean it up
3) Make it perform

The result of step one is at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gL96ukLx/2/

It uses only CSS and jQuery to perform the lines AND do the animation you requested.

Highlights are:

- CSS transition is used to handle the animation
- Heavy reliance on the jQuery offset to get the position of elements
- Timing is tricky because the user can click madly to make things misbehave
- Perhaps it would be better to disable the buttons to prevent further clicks until animation is complete
- An additional class of "showing" is used to alert CSS to animate the transitions
- Thin divs are used for the vertical lines, a short div is used for the horizontal line

Here is the meat of the result:

```
vert1
    .addClass('showing')
    .css(
    {   height: vertHeight,
        top: vertline1Top,
        left: vertline1Left
    });
    horz
        .addClass('showing')
        .css(
        {   width: horzWidth,
            left: vertline1Left,
            top: (vertline1Top + vertHeight)
        });
    vert2
        .addClass('showing')
        .css(
        {   height: vertHeight,
            left: vertline2Left,
            top: (vertline1Top + vertHeight)
        });
```

I set the position and length/width of each of three divs: vert1, vert2, and horz. The CSS transition will animate the change of size in a second. I present the first vertical line with no delay, the horizontal line with a 1 second delay (the time it takes the first vertical line to draw), and the second vertical line with a 2 second delay (the time it takes both the first vertical line and the horizontal line to draw).

Please note! This is a quick and dirty proof of concept to show that the result can be achieved with jQuery and CSS. It may or may not be suitable for your personal need. I haven't even thought about step 2 in my process. :P

Good luck!